# Loading HTML in WebView with custom CSS from non asset folder

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I have some `CSS` files and `JS` files in the `/data/data/my.package/files/htmlstuff` directory. I also have a bunch of HTML content with me obtained from the network. I want to apply these local `CSS` and `JS` to every html I load in the WebView. How can I achieve this?

If my `CSS` and `JS` were located in the `assets/htmlstuff` directory then I can use the below piece of code:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/htmlstuff/", htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

But how do I achieve the same when the files are present in `/files/` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is the below piece of code:

```
final File filesDir = getContext().getFilesDir();
final File htmlStuffDir = new File(filesDir, "htmlStuff");
final String baseUrlPath = htmlStuffDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///" + baseUrlPath, htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

The `/` at the end is important and it wouldn't work without that.